# Approval Workflow system needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow

I am looking for an Approval Workflow system that can integrate with our business logic.  Something with an API that the business logic can call to get the approvals, and that can call the the business logic API once it has the approvals.  It should allow department admins to be able to configure who needs to give the approvals.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions).

***AWS Step Functions** is a low-code visual workflow service used to orchestrate AWS services, **automate business processes**, and build serverless applications. Workflows manage failures, retries, parallelization, service integrations, and observability so developers can focus on higher-value business logic.*

Comment: I was looking for something that allows the end user admin to manage approvals (who and sequence, for example 2 developers followed by devops engineer), and also handles the actual approvals, so that the business logic developers don't need to manage that.

For example, business logic needs an approval set: calls approval system to get approvals (include callback API). After approvals complete, calls business logic with callback.

I don't want to write that approval system from scratch.